# How to ignore an ajax timeout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout

We want to leave the decision to the user to cancel (abort) the request or waiting for the response. When an timeout occurs, an confirm dialog should appear that offers the user the opportunity to wait for the response or abort the request:

```
$.ajax({
    [...]
    timeout: 2000,
    success: function(data) {   
        [...]
    };   
});


$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(data, textStatus, pStatusDescription) {

         if(textStatus === "timeout")
         {
            if(confirm("Do you want to wait for the response?"))
            {
                // continue request
            }
            else
            {
                // abort request
            }
         }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other way, by setting timeout independently of ajax request:

```js
let xhr;

const timeout = setTimeout(() => {
  if(confirm("Do you want to wait for the response?")) {
    // may be some code here
  } else {
    xhr.abort()
  }
}, 2000);

xhr = $.ajax({
  [...]
  error: function() {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  success: function(data) {
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  
    [...]
  };   
});
```

Comment: well you would want to remove the timeout in the Ajax call or set it to a really large number